# My app is creating new intent, I want my old intance of app (if running) when I start app

Tags: android, android-activity, launchmode

I am working on an app. Its' a single page stopwatch app. So when I press home button and start it again or run from running apps it creates new instance of app. I want previous current running instance.

I googled this and found that I need to set launch mode.  So, I did something like below. But nothing is working. It's still the same.

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"  
        >  


@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(INSTANCE_STATUS, super.onSaveInstanceState());
    bundle.putDouble(STATUS_ANGLE, curAngle);
    return bundle;
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");
    if (state instanceof Bundle)
    {
        Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable(INSTANCE_STATUS));
        curAngle= bundle.getDouble(STATUS_ANGLE);
        curTime = (int) (60 / (2 * Math.PI) * curAngle* 60);
        return;
    }
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
```

One more thing: it's based on timer.  Does it mean my app has to be running in background?

Answer (score 0):

You should save the state of your activity using `onSaveInstanceState`, and load it back using `onRestoreInstanceState`. You can read about it at the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

Comment: i have these two function already. but still not working. I also want to keep running my app. so that i can get the currently running state.

Comment: One more thing its based on timer.  Does it mean my app has to be running in background?

Comment: I am a little confused, the method onSaveInstanceState's signature is this: `protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)` NOT  `protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState()`

Comment: Oh i just went through the docmentation and came to know, this method is in the View class. You have to save and restore instance for the Activity.